# Trying to cast element ID to class selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fk434/

The code:

```
$('.theHider').click(function () {
    $("'." + $(this).id + "'").hide();
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="cola">This will be cola</div>
<div class="cola">This will be cola</div>
<div class="birch">This will be birch</div>
<div class="cola">This will be cola</div>
<div class="cola">This will be cola</div>
<div class="orange">This will be orange</div>
<div class="birch">This will be birch</div>
<div id="cola" class="theHider">This will hide cola</div>
<div id="birch" class="theHider">This will hide birch</div>
<div id="orange" class="theHider">This will hide orange</div>
```

I can't understand why this doesn't work.

As for document ready etc etc, I took it out when it was preventing jsfiddle from working.

Comment: Thanks guys, changing the quotes seemed to work. As for the $(this).id vs. this.id, I had tried both with the wrong quotes and neither had worked, but thanks. It works now, but a clarifying question about the quotes: to mimic $('.sampleSelector') <-- this element, wasn't I formatting it correctly? wouldn't what I changed it to make the selector $(.className), against jQuery syntax?

Answer (score 6):

`id` is a property of the DOM element itself, not the jQuery wrapper, so it should be `this.id`, not `$(this).id`. You also have some extraneous quotes that need to be removed:

```
$('.theHider').click(function () {
    $("." + this.id).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

It's your quotations that stops it from working, the selector gets invalid. Try this:

```
$('.' + this.id).hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no field `$(selector).id` you're mixing javascript elements with this jquery element.

Try this:

```
$('.theHider').click(function() {
  var selector = "."+$(this).prop("id");
  $(selector).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have inserted too many quotes into your selector.

```
$( "'." + this.id + "'" ).hide();
// ^----------------^------ these are not needed
```

You don't have to add the single quotes - just build your selector normally -

```
$( "." + this.id ).hide();
```

[Here is a fixed version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fk434/2/)

Make sure to check your JavaScript console whenever you are having problems. With your original code, there was this error on the same line as the selector you were building:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.cola'

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the problem:

```
$('.' + this.id)
```

However, I would like to bring data attributes to your attention:

```
<div class="theHider" data-tohide="cola">This will hide cola</div>
```

This allows you to use the identifier for something else if you need to; the click handler looks like this:

```
$('.theHider').on('click', function() {
    $('.' + $(this).data('tohide')).hide();
});
```